# Where can I find parts for attic pulldown stairs?

Tags: attic, stairs

I need two rollers replaced in my attic loft pull down staircase - the big ones on the picture. These drums have tension spring inside that helps to pull the stairs up and down.

The mechanism is quite similar to sectional garage doors but garage door contractors I have called would not even go past "oh, we only do garage doors"

Where would I look for these parts? Or for a whole new rope system if nothing else.

(I have no idea who and when built that staircase)

[image: staircase]

Comment: @mikes, please enter answers as answers instead of comments.

Comment: Have you tried looking for any manufacturers tags or labels on the frame? If there are none look on line for pull down staircase makers. If you find something even similar see if thet have a local installer/dealer

Comment: Disagree with recommendation to close - this question isn't  localized - it's asking what a part is called.

Comment: @mikes Sorry for the confusion. You were right the first time. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6369655#6369655

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to go directly to the manufacturer for this one. The only thing I've seen from the HI stores are fold down style of stairs.

For your pull down style, the first result I found in a Google search (so no affiliation or endorsement) is [Bessler Stairway Company](http://bessler.com/Bparts.html). They have parts for door and stringer spring tension drums, pulleys for the door cables, and the cables for the door and stringers. If you cannot identify your model, you may want to contact a manufacturer to see if their parts are generic or interchangeable with other manufacturers, or if they can help identify your model.

Comment: Thank you! There are no labels, apparently it was built with the house 30 years ago, but Bessler company you found has model 100 that looks just like what I have! Will give them a call. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

the mechanism is called a mechanical spring reel. Mine broke too, and im looking at this as a replacement: https://www.hunterspringandreel.com/products/mechanical-cable-reels/bracket-mounted-reels

Comment: this isn't a spring loaded device which is what the OP needs.